# Input in javascript alert

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am not sure, how we would use Selenium Python to enter text in the Javascript prompt asking for username and password?

Can anyone please advise the code for it?

I know how to switch_to_alert, and accept or reject it.

But not sure how to update the username and password in it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
prompt = Alert(driver) prompt.send_keys("TEXT")
prompt.accept()
```

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, code only answers are not high quality. A better answer would explain what the code does, tell where to insert it, explain why this approach was taken, and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Hello Stephen, Thank you for replying.
I am trying to use proxies.

When I open a link in chromdriver... it creates a username and password prompt.

I need to automate that entry